# SDK Platforms for API levels >11 not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

All- I went back to my SDK manager to download the SDK platforms for Android 2.2 and 2.3 (API Level 8 and 10) but was met with the following screen:
[image]

As you can see, there is no SDK Platform download under API 10 and 8, (not to mentiontion that  there are no other API levels at all, no API 5,6,7), only the extras for that platform (eg. Dual Screen API). Anybody have any ideas?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update ADT Plugin for Eclipse (Help->Check for Updates). Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Certain API levels are not shown as they are deprecated. To show these, check the `Obsolete` option in the bottom bar. Also, to see the API for JellyBean, you'll have to update your tools to rev 20.

Comment: Unfortunately checking obsolete did not do anything. Could it be that something is wrong with my system?

Comment: Perhaps. When I check Obsolete, I can see APIs back till 3.

Comment: Do you see the SDK Platform download under it? I don't see that under 8 or 10 and I am still not seeing any >8

Comment: Well, yes. But that may be because I have them all installed.

Comment: Ok. Probably something wrong with my system. When I tried to update I got the following error: Warning the following process adb.exe, cmd.exe, and java.exe have locked C:\android-sdk\tools.                                   Any ideas?

Comment: @androdcurious: If you are an Eclipse user, try doing the update from inside of Eclipse, rather than running the SDK Manager standalone.

Comment: @CommonswareSo launch the SDK manager from inside of Eclipse than update?

Comment: Then please add it as an answer and accept it, so that this question can be closed.